# "which" sometimes includes an extra backslash in bash

Tags: bash, shell, path

When looking for java, I typed "which java" in terminal. Printed "/usr/bin//java." The double "/" shouldn't be there. What's going on?

Comment: This is a (mild) misbehavior of the `which` *program*: Bash’s built-in `type` discards the extra `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the PATH had /usr/bin/ in it, and the extra "/" was picked up. Changing the path to contain /usr/bin with no trailing "/" fixed the problem.

Comment: This is not a problem. The path still works fine in all contexts.

Comment: Maybe. It sure confused me.